# get count of rows where user id w.r.t to sender

Tags: mysql, sql

I have built a private messaging system :

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sender varchar(255),
receiver varchar(255),
 msg varchar(255),
 date timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);





INSERT INTO tblA (sender, receiver,msg,date ) VALUES
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:13:29'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:14:09'),
('2', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:15:09'),
('2', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:16:09'),
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:17:09'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:18:19'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:19:29'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:10:09'),
('3', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:21:09'),
('3', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:22:09'),
('3', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:24:09'),
('3', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:25:19'),
('1', '3', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:26:29'),
('1', '3', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09'),
('2', '3', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:28:09'),
('2', '3', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:29:09'),
('1', '2', 'check3 ...','2011-08-21 14:23:09');
```

How to get count of user interatcing with sender and vice versa for different user.For eg: `1-2,2-1` is same count and  `1-1` is same count and `1-3,3-1` is same count and `2-3,3-2` is same count.Basically count of all interactions between the user-sender,sender-user .

Desired output (if I am user 1)

```
 sender   receiver    count
    3        1         4 
    1        1         2 
    2        1         9
```

I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please give some desired output example

Comment: if I am user 1 then count for 1 with 2 is 9 and 1 with 3 is 5 and 1 with 1 is 2 .I want the following count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original answer is gone, so allow me to post this again:

```
SELECT
 LEAST(sender, receiver) as X,
 GREATEST(sender, receiver) as Y,
 COUNT(1)
FROM
 tblA
GROUP BY
 X, Y;
```

This will select every set of interaction between two people.  As you requested, you won't be able to tell who contacted who.  You'll just be able to tell how many interactions there have been between two people.

And [here's the fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/811cc/2/0) I did yesterday.

Comment: Yes.  Why wouldn't it work?  What special case can you think of that wouldn't work?

Comment: I dont know there were many answers to the same q .I am just curious to know .Also can you please look into this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242666/private-chat-android-php-mysql  .Can you suggest me an approach

Answer (score 0):

this i think works and outputs what you asked. I'm not a fan of the squared group by, because for example 23*23+89*89 = 8450 = 13*13 + 91*91 (but i might have missed something)

```
select one, two, if(one=two,sum(cnt)/2,sum(cnt)) AS NUMBER from
(
select sender as one,receiver as two, count(*) as cnt from tblA group by sender, receiver
union all
select receiver as one ,sender as two, count(*) as cnt from tblA group by sender, receiver
) a
group by one, two
order by one, two
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d150/15

Comment: WHat about this :     `SELECT
 LEAST(sender, receiver) as X,
 GREATEST(sender, receiver) as Y,
 COUNT(1)
FROM
 tblA
GROUP BY
 X, Y;`       How about this ? this has no square and is working what do you think ?

Comment: it does not output all combinations (so every user's point of view), which mine does.  I realize it's maybe not what you need, though :)